# Is there support for creating a new file viewer for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

The google drive viewer looks ok, but it lacks some features that we might be interested in adding. Is there a way to write our own file manager for google drive - using the web browser and /or android, etc as a client?

Comment: Do you want to replace just the fileviewer or are you talking about a new client to Google Drive?

Comment: I guess I am talking about an iPhone client that would be more feature rich. But it would be a file viewer, along with being able to open apps registered for each file type, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-write a file viewer using the [Document list API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) but you will loose  some features such as:

- Google.com cookie based auth: You would have to implement an OAuth 2 flow + cookies
- User-installed Drive Application: [Users can install Drive Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview) and can open files using these apps directly from Drive. It won't be possible for your app to know what Drive Apps the user has installed and which file types they are allowed to open.

Answer (score 1):

You can now query which apps a user has installed.

Quoting https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps:
"The apps resource provides a list of the apps that a user has installed, with information about each app's supported MIME types, file extensions, and other details. 
For a list of methods for this resource, see the end of this page."